# show different values of an array with shift and concat

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I have this in my js:

```js
const allPromos = document.querySelector('.promo');
const titles = ['text number one', 'text number two'];

function showTitle() {
  const first = titles.shift();
  this.titles = titles.concat(first);
  allPromos.textContent = titles;
}

window.setInterval(() => {
  showTitle();
}, 2000);
```

In my HTML I have

```html
<h1 class="promo"></h1>
```

I wanted that the different values of the array would show every 2 seconds on the HTML.
So first would show "text number one", then would go to "text number two" and then again to "text number one".

I saw this in Nuxtjs and was working fine. I thought to apply it to vanilla js. But something is missing. It shows the text but only once...Should I add a loop to it?
Then it might become too complicated no?
I was just trying to find what is the simplest way with modern javascript.
What you think is the best approach nowadays?
Thank you for your thoughts

Comment: `this.titles = titles.concat(first);` -> `titles = titles.concat(first);` no need for `this`

Comment: Actually, then this code doesn't make much sense. You still shouldn't use `this` but the whole operation is weird. You just want to take the first item, show it, and add it to the end of the array. No need to `concat`, or to overwrite the array, or to assign the entire array to `.textContent`

Comment: You're right @VLAZ. In the first part, I change it and then forget to edit it before putting it here.
I think I just was trying to add new array methods to make the same as a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let allPromos = document.querySelector('.promo');
let titles = ['text number one', 'text number two'];
let i=0

function showTitle() {
  //i%titles.length for loop
  //i for one cicle
  allPromos.textContent = titles[i%titles.length];
  i++
}

window.setInterval(() => {
  showTitle();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 class="promo"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generalise the repetition of the array to a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). This is very simple using [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) to infinitely give out the array values always restarting from the beginning:

```
function* repeat(arr) {
  while (true)           //repeat forever
    yield* arr.values(); //delegate to array iterator
}
```

With this generalised repetition, you can just take the next item from the iterator and just show it:

```js
/* library code */
function* repeat(arr) {
  while (true)
    yield* arr.values();
}
/* /library code */

const allPromos = document.querySelector('.promo');
const titles = [
  'text number one', 
  'text number two', 
  'text number three', 
  'text number four', 
  'text number five'
];

function showTitle(title) {
  allPromos.textContent = title;
}

const it = repeat(titles);

window.setInterval(() => {
  const title = it.next().value;
  showTitle(title);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 class="promo"></h1>
```

For more information, see MDN:
[Iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)
[Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

If you want to avoid the extra free variable outside `setInterval`, it can be converted to a parameter:

```
window.setInterval((it) => {
  showTitle(it.next().value);
}, 1000, repeat(titles));
```